# Remove Directive From Dom using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In internet explorer, input type ="date" does not work and angular directive pitches in to show jqueryUI datetimepicker.

But, In chrome, both are displaying , is there any way to remove the directive from the element using jquery such that when it allows the input type date, the only html5 datetime is taken?

html:

```
<input id="date1" type="date" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker/>
<br/>
{{ date }}
```

javascript :

```
var datePicker = angular.module('app', []);

datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#date1').removeAttr('jqdatepicker');
if ($('#date1')[0].type != 'date') {

}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TAeNF/1420/

Comment: Don't use jQuery to remove an angular directive.... use angular to determine if the directive should / should not be applied.

Comment: if we want to remove through jQuery what is the code? or we cant?

Comment: No.  It's possible.  It's just not the "angular way".  You're mixing up angular and jQuery, and you can do this purely with angular.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by conditionally returning from the directive

http://jsfiddle.net/TAeNF/1421/

```
if ($('#date1')[0].type != 'date') {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    }
    else
    return null;
});
```